# Spark job can't connect to cassandra when ran from a jar

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, jar, spark-cassandra-connector

I have spark job that writes data to Cassandra(Cassandra is on GCP). When I run this from IntelliJIDEA (my IDE) it works perfectly fine. The data is perfectly sent and written to Cassandra. However, this fails when I package my project into a fat jar and run it.

Here is an example of how I run it.

```
spark-submit --class com.testing.Job --master local out/artifacts/SparkJob_jar/SparkJob.jar 1 0
```

However, this fails for me and gives me the following errors

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to open native connection to Cassandra at {X.X.X:9042} :: 'com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.config.ProgrammaticDriverConfigLoaderBuilder com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.config.DriverConfigLoader.programmaticBuilder()'


Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.config.ProgrammaticDriverConfigLoaderBuilder com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.config.DriverConfigLoader.programmaticBuilder()'
```

My artifacts file does include the spark-Cassandra files

```
spark-cassandra-connector-driver_2.12-3.0.0-beta.jar
spark-cassandra-connector_2.12-3.0.0-beta.jar
```

I'm wondering why this is happening and how I can fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that besides that 2 things, you need to have more jars - full Java driver, and its dependencies.  You have following possibilities to fix that:

1. You need to make sure that these artifact is packaged into the resulting jar (so-called "fat jar" or an "assembly") using Maven or SBT, or anything else
2. you can can specify maven coordinates `com.datastax.spark:spark-cassandra-connector_2.12:3.0.0-beta` with `--packages` like this `--packages com.datastax.spark:spark-cassandra-connector_2.12:3.0.0-beta`
3. you can download [spark-cassandra-connector-assembly](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.datastax.spark/spark-cassandra-connector-assembly_2.12/3.0.0-beta) artifact to the node from which you're doing `spark-submit`, and then use that file name with `--jars`

See the [documentation for Spark Cassandra Connector](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/b3.0/doc/0_quick_start.md) for more details.

Comment: Great I tried 2 and 3 and it worked perfectly. I thought I was originally trying #1 (since I made a fat jar and used sbt)

Comment: I usually check fat jar by doing unzip -l jar-file|grep class-name   - I’m not sbt expert, and can’t say why it wasn’t packaged